# Cypher: Query to Combine Collection for InFeed Ads (Show 1 Ad Every X Amount of Posts)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to build a Cypher query which allows me to build in-feed ads:

An example is how on the Facebook Mobile App an ad appears inside the feed for every X numbers of posts (Lets say 1 ad for every 5 posts on same feed).

So far I have this: "MATCH (P:Post) (A:Ad) return P,A"

Post would be the User's Posts.
Ad would be ads to put inside a User's feed.

I'm able to get both collections, but am lost on how to combine this to create an effect similar to in-Feed apps.

Comment: After a quick read, I guess SKIP and/or FOREACH could help.

Answer (score 0):

What is your actual use-case?

Do you have a feed of Ads somewhere and want to merge it with user's posts?

How do you model ad-feeds and post-feeds?

You probably also have Ad-Publishers, Categories etc? Same for posts?

So something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User {login:"john"})-[:POSTED]->(p:Post)
WITH p
LIMIT 20
MATCH (:Publisher {id:"3829472"})-[:PUBLISHED]->(ad:Ad)<-[:AD_CATEGORY]-(c)-[:POST_CATEGORY]->(p)
RETURN p,case when random() < 0.2 then ad else null end
```

You should probably look into graph modeling.

For actual cypher questions check the [manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) and the [refcard](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/).